# gradle-git: merging is failing, even though there are no conflicts

Tags: git, gradle, groovy

I am using [gradle-git](https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-git).  I have defined 2 tasks as follows:

**PrepareTask.groovy**

```
class PrepareTask extends DefaultTask {
  public String branch

  private Grgit git

  @TaskAction
  public void executeTask(){
    try {
      git = Grgit.open(dir: project.rootProject.projectDir)
    } catch (RepositoryNotFoundException e) {
      println("Git is not available in this project.")
    }
    if (git){
      def currentBranch = git.branch.getCurrent().getName()
      if (currentBranch != branch){
        git.checkout(branch: branch, createBranch: true)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**CommitTask.groovy**

```
class CommitTask extends DefaultTask {
  public String prev_branch
  public String message = "committing changes"

  private Grgit git

  @TaskAction
  public void executeTask(){
    try {
      git = Grgit.open(dir: project.rootProject.projectDir)
    } catch (RepositoryNotFoundException e) {
      println("Git is not available in this project.")
    }

    if (git){
      git.add(patterns: ['.'])
      def commit = git.commit(message: message, all: true)
      if (prev_branch){
        def branch = git.branch.getCurrent().getName()
        git.checkout(branch: prev_branch, createBranch: false)
        git.merge(head: branch, mode: MergeOp.Mode.CREATE_COMMIT, message: "merging")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have an `updateSource` task in gradle that works fine, and I've set the following in **build.gradle**:

```
task prepare(type: PrepareTask){
  branch = 'changes-branch'
}

task commit(type: CommitTask){
  prev_branch = 'current-branch'
}

updateSource.dependsOn prepare
updateSource.finalizedBy commit
```

Everything executes, the new branch gets created and checked out, the source code gets updated and committed, then the original branch gets checked out again.  But when the task attempts to merge the branches, it fails:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':commit'.
> Problem merging.
```

adding the `--stacktrace` option shows:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':commit'.
        ...
Caused by: org.ajoberstar.grgit.exception.GrgitException: Problem merging.
        ...
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.CheckoutConflictException: Checkout conflict with files:
```

But that doesn't make any sense for two reasons.  1. The checkout succeeds fine, and 2. I started with a clean branch.